# the image size is too big to pass into another activity (array byteArray ) is too big for high-quality images)

Tags: android, arrays, image, byte, outputstream

Please help me on how to save the image to the device then get it in the next activity.
I was told that if I want to use high quality images, don't pass it in the Intent.
I have to save images to the device that way it doesn't need to be passed in intents but I'm not sure how

This is my onPostExecute code

```
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Face[] faces) {
            pd.dismiss();
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ResultActivity.class);
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            String data = gson.toJson(faces);
            if (faces == null || faces.length == 0) {
                makeToast("No faces detected. You may not have added the API Key or try retaking the picture.");
            } else {
                intent.putExtra("list_faces", data);
                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                mBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

                intent.putExtra("image", byteArray);
                startActivity(intent);
            }

        }
    };
    detectTask.execute(inputStream);
}
```

Comment: save in internal cache then in the second activity with fileInputstream fetch it.

Comment: can I have the example code please @hamid

Answer (score 1):

in the first activity save bitmap on the internal memory

```
 fun saveFile(bitmap: Bitmap, context: Context):String?{
    var fileName:String?= "myImage"
    try {
        val fo = context.openFileOutput(fileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fo)
        fo.close()
    } catch (e:Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        fileName = null
    }
    return fileName;
}
```

put fileName in extra and send it for second activity:

```
    val filename=saveFile(bitmap,requireContext())
    val intent = Intent(getApplicationContext(), ResultActivity.class)
    intent.putExtra("fileName", filename)
    startActivity(intent)
```

and in second activity you can have the bitmap :

```
val fileName = intent.getStringExtra("fileName")
val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(context.openFileInput(fileName))
```

Comment: I have to removed the intent in the onPostExecute is it? And replaced the code you mentioned here?

Comment: Do away with that ByteArrayOutputStream. You can directly compress to the outputstream `fo`.

Comment: @hamid It gives me so much error. could you please link your code with my code up there. I'm not sure how to implement your code.

Comment: just convert kotlin to java